# What is the use of org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor in struts and java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException

Tags: jboss, struts-1, jboss-eap-7

We ran into a migration issue where in we are migrating an application from JBoss 4.2.1.GA to JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA. The exception encountered is as below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException:
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:226)
```

So we have a fix for the same which involves

Adding the below in the struts config.xml file.

this line in config

```
<controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor"
            locale="true" nocache="false" contentType="text/html; charset= UTF8">
   <set-property property="maxFileSize" value="7M"/>
</controller>
```

has been changes to 
 tag from charset= UTF8 to charset= ISO-8859-1"
and an additional property

This has resolved the issue but wants to know what is the proper use of class ComposableRequestProcessor. And why it is helping our solution here.

We don't see a proper document or blog on the net explaining why and when we need to add this configration. What is the advantage of doing so?

*Also, we want to know JBoss 4.2.1.GA the page-context encoding was not enforced but in JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA we need to define it as ISO else it won't work in windows server environment.
We know it has to do with some Undertow implementation over the earlier Apache Tomcat HTTPs implementation framework used by JBoss.*

Any help by pointing to right document or information is widely appreciated.

Comment: The root cause is Null encoding has been set on the response..  Ensure a null or invalid encoding has not been set on the response

Comment: The problem is in the target page. It is not well-formed at all.

When parsing the page, JSoup tries to fix the page and for one thing, parses the content type to "text/html; charset='iso-8859-1'"(with the single quotes included).

It then passes this string(with the single quotes) and uses it to get the charset:

Charset.forName("'ISO-8859-1'");

which fails.

The problem is in the target page. Maybe you can use this alternative instead, which doesn't parse the charset from the page